# Save currently selected < li > in Angular after page refresh

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a sidebar that's global to the app and its HTML is in main.html, where I also have a ui-view that injects, depending on the state, partial HTML like specific info for stores, retailers, etc.

When I click on the sidebar < li > elements they become "active" and highlighted, while the previous one becomes not "active". It's working fine, however, when I refresh my page, the "active" < li > is lost and it goes back to the default "active" < li >.

I was thinking of on each controller to the page, through the ID's passed by params and assigning id tags to the elements such as < id = "store_1" >, search for the specific element and make it "active". However this is partially DOM manipulation and it shouldn't be done on Controllers but I don't know a different alternative!

EDIT: I remembered now I could do a simple script on the html file and use JQuery but that isnt' optimal either, I believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a service to handle saving the currently selected item to a persistent storage of your choosing. It could be cookies, webstorage, rest call...

```js
angular.module('MyApp',[]).
controller('MyController',['MySelectionService',function(MySelectionService){
  var myController = this;
  myController.listItems= ["item1","item2","item3"];
  myController.selected = MySelectionService.getSelected();
  myController.changeSelection = function(selectedItem){
      MySelectionService.setSelected(selectedItem);
      myController.selected = MySelectionService.getSelected();
  };
  
}]).
service('MySelectionService',[function(){
  var mySelectionService = {};
  var selected = "item1";
  mySelectionService.getSelected = function(){
    /* Retrieve from persistant storage */
    return selected;
  };
  mySelectionService.setSelected = function(newSelection){
    /* Save to persistant storage */
    selected = newSelection;
  }
  return mySelectionService;
}]);
```

```css
.selected{
  color:red;  
  
}
li{
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<ul ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MyController as myController">
  <li ng-repeat="listItem in myController.listItems" ng-class="{'selected':listItem === myController.selected}" ng-click="myController.changeSelection(listItem)">
    {{listItem}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

This is simple. Have a look at window.sessionStorage. You can store the name of the current selected item and then retrieve it.  You can write a factory like this.

```
 .factory('ActiveState', function (){

   return {

     store_state: function(name){
       window.sessionStorage.setItem('name', name);
     },


    get_state: function(){
      return window.sessionStorage.getItem("name");
    }
   };
 });
```